# How to print page without print preview from Stimulsoft in Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, printing, stimulsoft, print-preview

I want to run the print order when I type this url and print my desired document.

This is the url that calls this method:

`http://localhost:9090/api/printPage`

**Api method**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("PrintPage")]
public boolean PrintPage()
{
    try
    {       
        var p = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person() {Id = 1, FirstName = "omid", LastName = "nasri", Gender = true}
            , new Person() {Id = 2, FirstName = "hana", LastName = "akbari", Gender = false}
            , new Person() {Id = 3, FirstName = "ali", LastName = "jahani", Gender = true }
            , new Person() {Id = 4, FirstName = "sara", LastName = "sabori", Gender = false }
        };

        var mainReport = new StiReport();

        mainReport.Load(@"D:\WebSite\Web\Print\Report.mrt");
        mainReport.RegBusinessObject("persons" , p);

        mainReport.Print(false);

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }    
}
```

[image: Screen Shot Business Object persons]

I use stimulsoft 2012.1.

Comment: What happens when you debug through the code?

Comment: It does not happen, and the print does not work. Is there any problem with the code? I use stimulsoft 2012. @mjwills

Comment: hi @MohammadSalmanian did you manage this at the end if you still remember? because there are still no easy workaround for printing issue from web with stimul...